# Using selenium to click a dropdown menu within a secondary menu

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am using selenium to login to a website and load a dropdown menu. Inside this menu there is a secondary menu that has a link to download a csv file.
Using the following code, I can do all of those steps except click the option within the secondary menu:

```
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element(By.ID,"user_email").send_keys(user)
driver.find_element(By.ID,"user_password").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element(By.ID,"submit").click()
sleep(5)

driver.find_element(By.ID, "table-actions").click()
open_win_elem = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"table-actions-menu-parent").click()
sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "table-actions-menu-sub-option table-actions-option").click()  #this is where the last click doesnt happen
```

When I inspect the dropdown menu item that I wish to click, it looks like this:

Download / Copy PlayerList

```
        <div class="menu-top-options">
            <div class="table-actions-option-radio-container">
                <label><input type="radio" name="players-to-include" value="all" checked="">All Players</label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="players-to-include" value="filtered">Filtered</label>
            </div>
            <label class="table-actions-option-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="include-grouped-columns-header" checked="">Include Grouped Columns Header</label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="table-actions-menu-sub-option table-actions-option" data-action="downloadPlayerlist">Download CSV Format<i class="csv-icon fas fa-file-csv"></i></div>
        <div class="table-actions-menu-sub-option table-actions-option" data-action="downloadPlayerlistXLSX">Download XLSX Format<i class="excel-icon fas fa-file-excel"></i></div>
        <div class="table-actions-menu-sub-option table-actions-option" data-action="copyPlayerlist">Copy to Clipboard<i class="copy-icon fas fa-copy"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This returns the following error:

```
File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".table-actions-menu-sub-option table-actions-option"}
```

Is there something else required to similate this particular click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `By.CLASS_NAME` only takes one class name as an argument. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-class-name

Perhaps try using `By.CSS_SELECTOR` and making the argument a CSS selector that looks for both classes.

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".table-actions-menu-sub-option.table-actions-option").click()
```

Comment: you are right `CLASS_NAME` expects only one class and it converts it to `CSS_SELECTOR` by adding dot at the beginning of name. But if you add manually dots to other classes (except first) then it will work. `(By.CLASS_NAME, "table-actions-menu-sub-option.table-actions-option")`